# Should steak be broiled crosswise or lengthwise?

Tags: steak

When broiling steak in an oven, is there any difference between positioning the steak lengthwise or crosswise relative to the flame?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by “crosswise” or “lengthwise”? I am trying to picture the setup, but can’t quite imagine what you mean.

Comment: I think "parallel" vs. "perpendicular" to the flame -- not positive though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in whether you place your steak perpendicular or parallel to the flame, however, what's your goal?  If you want a crust or char over most of the surface, you would probably want to turn it part way through the cooking.